# Another term for "zero-sum game"

Tags: terminology, technical, synonyms

Rock-paper-scissors is a zero-sum game, however I remember a different phrase that means essentially the same thing - when each member of a group of objects has exactly balanced strengths and weaknesses.

Edit: The phrase I'm looking for is not a synonym for zero-sum game, I'm looking for something that describes a scenario in which A trumps B, B trumps C, and C trumps A. Are there any words that describe non-linear ranking?

Comment: A *zero sum game* does not describe a game in which "every participant has exactly balanced strengths and weaknesses", it describes a game where the outcome is such that whatever one member gains, another member must have necessarily lost. There is no input or winnings from the outside to compete for.

Comment: @DanBron so I'm looking for a word that describes a different trait of Rock-paper-scissors

Comment: Since the example is incorrect I'll ignore it.  What about deadlock.  I've also hear fungible used in push there, pop out here.  Does that make it balanced?

Comment: It's rather "non-transitive" ordering than "non-linear" ranking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise is incorrect.

Comment: Wikipedia describes RPS as a "zero sum game"

Comment: Not exactly what you described, but a "Mexican Standoff" is somewhat similar to a 'zero sum game'.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that a **symmetric opponent game** or simply a **symmetric game**. I don't see it as a common phrase since most games are assumed symmetric unless stated otherwise.

I'm not sure BoardGameGeek.com is a valid citation, but...
https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/636692/game-balance-symmetry-vs-asymmetry

Comment: I disagree that games are assumed symmetric unless stated otherwise. It may be true in certain contexts though. Would you care to clarify what context you're thinking about?

Comment: I suppose it also matter to what degree of symmetry we are talking, but if you were explaining Rock, Paper, Scissors, you would not have make a specific point to clarify that we both can use Rock. Or to say that my bishop in chess has the same movements as your bishop. Most people would assume this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

A **Nash Equilibrium** is where nobody can benefit by changing their strategy. That might be what you are thinking of.

> In game theory, the Nash equilibrium is a solution concept of a
>   non-cooperative game involving two or more players, in which each
>   player is assumed to know the equilibrium strategies of the other
>   players, and no player has anything to gain by changing only their own
>   strategy.

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Nash+Equlibrium